# Create Postgres Read-Write User and grant access to existing database

Tags: database, postgresql

I have an existing Postgres database with 2 schemas "public" and "dbo". The DB and schemas were created via master db user "postgres".

I want to create a new DB user with read-write access to my desired database. It should have access to both schemas and should have access to existing tables as well as the new tables that will be created.

I use below code to create DB user and access db from this user, but i get permission denied when accessing existing tables.

```
-- Create a new user with login capabilities
CREATE USER your_new_user WITH encrypted PASSWORD 'strong_password_here';

-- Grant connect privilege to the specific database
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE "DEMO_TEST" TO your_new_user;

-- Grant usage on all schemas within the specific database
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO your_new_user;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA dbo TO your_new_user;

-- Grant privileges on all existing objects in the schemas
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO your_new_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA public TO your_new_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO your_new_user;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA dbo TO your_new_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA dbo TO your_new_user;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA dbo TO your_new_user;

-- Set default privileges for future objects created by your_new_user in the schemas
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER your_new_user IN SCHEMA public
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO your_new_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER your_new_user IN SCHEMA public
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES TO your_new_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER your_new_user IN SCHEMA public
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS TO your_new_user;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER your_new_user IN SCHEMA dbo
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO your_new_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER your_new_user IN SCHEMA dbo
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES TO your_new_user;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER your_new_user IN SCHEMA dbo
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS TO your_new_user;
```

I also tried below code, but again i receive permission denied on accessing existing tables.

```
-- Read/write role
CREATE ROLE readwrite;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydatabase TO readwrite;
GRANT USAGE, CREATE ON SCHEMA myschema TO readwrite;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA myschema TO readwrite;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON TABLES TO readwrite;
GRANT USAGE ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA myschema TO readwrite;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA myschema GRANT USAGE ON SEQUENCES TO readwrite;

-- Users creation
CREATE USER app_user1 WITH PASSWORD 'some_secret_passwd';

-- Grant privileges to users
GRANT readwrite TO app_user1;
```

Comment: Could you provide the result of the command '\dp+' ? And have a look at the column Access privileges